# Callable in model field not called upon adding new object through Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default

we read that the callable of a default field value is called, every time a new object is created.

In my model I have:

`when_first_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())`

When in the admin page I create a new object I always get the same 
datetime, as if the callable is not called. Any ideas why?

It is as if something is cached somewhere and keeps the evaluated last call of the callable.

When I do a migrate it resets, but stays the same when adding new objects
until the next migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
when_first_upload = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

You need the callable itself, not the result returned by it.